# bind code behind method from xaml

Tags: wpf

I am learning wpf in my new project and am developing user control for game  application.

Sadly, I'm facing problem in binding the `behind` method in the below code to the `Button` `Command` property.

Here is my code:

**Codebehind:**

```
[Command]
public void OnButtonClick(object param)
{
    if (this.CustomClick != null)
        this.CustomClick(this);            
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsctrlCell" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              ItemsSource="{Binding  ElementName=userctrlGameBoard, Path= Dimension,Converter={StaticResource Convert}}" 
              Width="Auto"  
              Height="Auto" 
              Margin="77,92,-75.2,-92.4">

    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Border  BorderThickness="1" 
                     CornerRadius="15" 
                     Height="Auto" 
                     Width="Auto">
                <ItemsPresenter  Width="Auto" 
                                 Height="Auto" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Width="Auto" Height="Auto"></UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <WrapPanel x:Name="wrppanelCell"  
                       Width="Auto"
                       Height="Auto">

                <Button Name="btnCell" 
                        Width="40" 
                        Height="40" 
                        FontSize="25" 
                        FontWeight="Bold" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=userctrlGameBoard,Path=OnButtonClick}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                </Button>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How can I bind the `behind` method to the button command property?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your post a bit, and here's what I did: I fixed a few grammar and spelling mistakes in your post. Also, I replaced the "please help" message at the bottom. In general, Stack Overflow does not like to have "thanks" or "please help me" messages at the bottom of questions. Also, if you have method names, try to wrap them in ` characters, so they stand out more. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more info on formatting. Good luck! :)

Comment: I have never seen the `[Command]` decorator before, maybe you should have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/christian.php) to clear things out for you.

Comment: Did you set `DataContext=this` in your class constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# code is the code begind of this xaml file ? If yes why you want to bind ? When you do a Binding, you bind to a proprety, not to a function. You are supposed to bind your Command to a ICommand proprety. Here is what I do:

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    #region private fields
    private readonly Action execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> canExecute;
    #endregion

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public MyCommand(Action execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public MyCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null ? true : this.canExecute();
    }
}
```

Then you creat a ICommand proprety that you want to bind.

```
private ICommand inscription;

    public ICommand Inscription
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.inscription == null)
                this.inscription = new MyCommand(function_execute, function_canExecute);

            return this.inscription;
        }
    }
```

The function_execute is the function that will be triger, this other one allow you to check if you want that your function_execute will be execute.

In your Xaml:

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Connexion" Command="{Binding Inscription}"></Button>
```

But if you don't do MVVM, you should just use the code behind without binding I think, I'm not an expert too lol.

Comment: Good example. Small improvement: your execute-Action in MyCommand should be of type `Action<object>` so you can pass data via CommandParameter to it. Also the canExecute-Func should be of type `Predicate<object>` so it can take the same parameter as object

Answer (score 3):

Try this to create `Command bindings`.

In your **.xaml**:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="CloseCommand" Text=""/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Commandbindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource CloseCommand}" Executed="Close" />
</Window.Commandbindings>
```

Your `Button`:

```
<Button Command={StaticResource CloseCommand}" />
```

Your **.cs**:

```
public MainConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

public void Close(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Stuff that happens in your `Close command`
}
```